# Create react native app that will start with voice command like google assistant or alexa

Tags: voice-recognition, alexa-voice-service

I want to build an app in react native which will start when the user will say hey `[app name]` just like when you say `hey google` google assistant opens and for `amazon-echo`, `Alexa`.

I am using `react-native-voice` inside the app to recognize what I am saying but only after I click on the app and press the mic button inside my app.

Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

actualy you can use alexa sdk kit to make it just folow t[here](https://developer.amazon.com/en-IN/alexa/alexa-skills-kit)!

this medium tutorial will help you to build like what you want [link](https://medium.com/crowdbotics/how-to-build-a-custom-amazon-alexa-skill-step-by-step-my-favorite-chess-player-dcc0edae53fb)!

there is package to integrate with react-native
    npm i alexa-app

for more deep look this documentation
https://github.com/alexa-js/alexa-app#readme

Comment: Hi, This is not what I wanted. This link says it can only work on Amazon Devices but I want it to work on any device which have my app installed.

Comment: yes you make model with alexa developer kit and then import it on your app

Comment: Yeah. I will tryout and let you know. Thanks again